# Python converting "March 2 2012" into a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

When I call the following function, I get a struct_time obj. Is there a way to convert this into a date obj?

```
     import time

     date = time.strptime("March 2 2012", '%B %d %Y')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime("March 2 2012", '%B %d %Y').date()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
import dateutil.parser
datetime_obj  = dateutil.parser.parse("March 2 2012")
```

*edit:*

this returns a `datetime.datetime` object, not a `datetime.date` object:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 2, 0, 0) #opposed to datetime.date(2012, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds = time.strptime("March 2 2012", '%B %d %Y')
realdate = datetime.date(ds.tm_year, ds.tm_mon, ds.tm_mday)
```